# elixir - protocol Enumerable not implemented error when preload with empty roll

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I have this code:

```
q = from p in Case, where: p.user_id == ^user_id:
Repo.all(q)
|> Repo.preload(:helper)
```

with the view render function:

```
alias ChatWeb.HelperView

def render("api_case.json", %{case: case, message: message, token: token}) do
%{
status: "1",
token: token.token,
items: case.items,
helpers: render_many(case.helper, HelperView, "helper.json"),
}
end
```

if I have `helper` data, everything will be OK.

but if I don't have anything in `helper`, I will get:

> protocol Enumerable not implemented for
> #Ecto.Association.NotLoaded of type Ecto.Association.NotLoaded (a struct)

How can I resolve this?

Comment: why just not `render_many(case, ...)` instead of `render_many(case.helper, ...)`, it's easier to handle if there is no data in association, maybe?

Comment: It looks like the `helper` association (why isn't this called `helpers`?) is not preloaded. Are you sure you're posting/using the correct query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s not quite clear what do you mean “if I don’t have anything in helper,” but the following would likely do:

```elixir
def render("api_case.json", %{case: case, message: message, token: token}) do
  helpers =
    case case.helper do
      %Ecto.Association.NotLoaded{} -> []
      many -> render_many(many, HelperView, "helper.json")
    end
  %{status: "1", token: token.token, items: case.items, helpers: helpers}
end
```